Why is Google Sheets PHP API failing when I insert a line manually in Google Sheets?
I have a PHP script adding lines to a Google Spreadsheet. It all works perfectly fine.
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Google Sheets API");
$client->setScopes([Google_Service_Sheets::SPREADSHEETS]);
$client->setAccessType("offline");
$path = "credentials.json";
$client->setAuthConfig($path);

$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = '...';

$newrow = ["a", "b", "c"];
$rows = [$newrow];
$valueRange = new Google_Service_Sheets_ValueRange();
$valueRange->setValues($rows);
$range = "Blad1";
$options = ["valueInputOption" => "USER_ENTERED"];
$service->spreadsheets_values->append($spreadsheetId, $range, $valueRange, $options);

However, when I manually insert a line in the Google Spreadsheet, the PHP script fails to add new lines. This is the error message:

Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL
error 6: Could not resolve host: oauth2.googleapis.com (see
https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for
https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token

How can I make sure that the API still appends new lines whenever I have inserted a line manually?
I tried removing the manually inserted line and from then on it works fine again...

About How can I make sure that the API still appends new lines whenever I have inserted a line manually?, I think that Google Apps Script might be useful. But, about However, when I manually insert a line in the Google Spreadsheet, the PHP script fails to add new lines. This is the error message:, I cannot understand the logic for occurring the error. Can I ask you about the detailed flow for occuring the error?

Could not resolve host is a simple DNS, network or firewall failure. Unless you have a fundamental network problem, it's probably intermittent?? And this sounds like a call to the authentication service, so it's unclear if the append() function would really involve that. Are you certain that what you've posted is a [mre] of the issue? Does removing the call to append() consistently prevent this error? It all seeems a bit odd, frankly.

When I remove the append, there is no error. It's really strange, I don't understand why this is happening.
